# Fetch email ID from AdminDirectory directory using first name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to fetch the email ID of a user from the admin directory using his/her first name obtained from a spreadsheet, which simply checks if an email id exists in the directory and if yes shows his/her email id, here is my code:

```
function scanSsheet(){
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx').getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var getRange = originalSpreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var data = originalSpreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var volunteerFirstName = data[i][3];
    var volunteerLastName = data[i][4];

    Logger.log('****************Record No: ' + i + '****************');
    Logger.log('volunteerFirstName: ' + data[i][3]);
    Logger.log('volunteerLastName: ' + data[i][4]);

    Logger.log('fetchUser is called');
    var checkUser = fetchUser(volunteerFirstName);
    if(checkUser){
      Logger.log('Email exists');
    }
    else{
      Logger.log('The user doesnot exist in the directory');
    }

  }
}

//Checks if the user exists in the directory or not and display email id if yes
function fetchUser(volunteerFirstName){
   var isUser
   try{
    var email = AdminDirectory.Users.list({givenName: volunteerFirstName}); // This line should fetch email but it is not working
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);

    Logger.log('email:' +email);
    isUser = true;
   } catch (e){
    isUser = false;
   }
 return isUser;
}
```

As seen I have used `var email = AdminDirectory.users.list({givenName: volunteerFirstName})` as seen in the code for which I followed G-suite's [admin-sdk](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users), but I am not able retrieve the email id, am I doing anything wrong here? Also, I am newbie to google-apps script, please ignore if its a stupid question.

Comment: Can you share the logging/error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve it and a bunch of other details using [users-list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list):

```
function scanSsheet(){
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx').getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var getRange = originalSpreadsheet.getDataRange();
  var data = originalSpreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var volunteerFirstName = data[i][3];
    var volunteerLastName = data[i][4];

    Logger.log('****************Record No: ' + i + '****************');
    Logger.log('volunteerFirstName: ' + data[i][3]);
    Logger.log('volunteerLastName: ' + data[i][4]);

    Logger.log('fetchUser is called');
    fetchUser(volunteerFirstName);

  }
}

function fetchUser(volunteerFirstName){
   var pageToken;
   var membersList = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
       domain: 'mydomain.com',
       orderBy: 'email',
       query: volunteerFirstName,
       maxResults: 100,
       pageToken: pageToken
   });  
   Logger.log('membersList:' +membersList);
   }
```

Thanks.